# LSTM doesn't learn to add random numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I was trying to do a pretty simple thing, train an LSTM that picks a sequence of random numbers and outputs the sum of them. But after some hours without converging I decided to ask here which of my premises doesn't work.

The idea is simple:

1. I generate a training set of sequences of some sequence length of random numbers and label them with the sum of them (numbers are drawn from a normal distribution)
2. I use an LSTM with an RMSE loss for predicting the output, the sum of these numbers, given the sequence input

Intuitively the LSTM should learn to set the weight of the input gate to 1 (bias 0) the weights of the forget gate to 0 (bias 1) and the weight to the output gate to 1 (bias 0) and learn to add these numbers, but it doesn't. I pasting the code I use, I tried with different learning rates, optimizers, batching, observed the gradients and the outputs and don't find the exact reason why is failing.

Code for generating sequences:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def generate_sequences(n_samples, seq_len):
    total_shape = n_samples*seq_len
    random_values = np.random.randn(total_shape)
    random_values = random_values.reshape(n_samples, -1)
    targets = np.sum(random_values, axis=1)
    return random_values, targets
```

Code for training:

```
n_samples = 100000
seq_len = 2
lr=0.1
epochs = n_samples
batch_size = 1
input_shape = 1

data, targets = generate_sequences(n_samples, seq_len)
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, targets))
output = tf.keras.layers.RNN(tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(1, dtype='float64', recurrent_activation=None, activation=None), input_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, input_shape))
iterator = train_data.batch(batch_size).make_one_shot_iterator()
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)

for i in range(epochs):
    my_inp, target = iterator.get_next()
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(my_inp)
        my_out = output(tf.reshape(my_inp, shape=(batch_size,seq_len,1)))
        loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(target - my_out)),1)/batch_size

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, output.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, output.trainable_variables),
                                global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
```

I also has a conjecture that this a theoretical problem (If we sum different random values drawn form a normal distribution then the output is not in the [-1, 1] range and the LSTM due to the tanh activations can't learn it. But changing them doesn't improved the performance (changed to linear in the example code).

#### EDIT:

Set activations to linear, I realised that the `tanh()` squashes the values.

#### SOLVED:

The problem was actually the `tanh()` of the gates and recurrent states which was squashing my outputs and not allowing them to grow by adding up the summands. Putting all activations to linear works pretty fine.

Comment: There could be a number of issues with the network, but what i want to point out is that **this is the definition of over-engineering a problem**. You are using a complex solution to SUM things up. Other than that (i.e. probably this is not the type of problem NN were built for), you could try different activation function like linear (which is much simpler and actually just returns the sum of the layer)

Comment: @nickthefreak I'm pretty sure the OP isn't engineering a solution to their summing problem, but is just trying to learn to use this system with a simple example (addition).

Comment: I'd like to agree with @orlp, i recently tried this to a basic approach of finding the multiplication table to gf(8), however, not much of a luck with linear models, have to try to incorporate LSTMS maybe.

Comment: Yes, as @orlp says it's not about finding an efficient solution to some problem, but about performing an experiment and understanding its result. But following the @nickthefreak hint, I changed the activations to linear as the `tanh()` function in the output gate should avoid the LSTM to learn to accumulate the sum (it squashes it). Still not working.

Comment: during your tests, what is the output you are getting? moreover, i'd use float32 instead of float64, also put the last two lines of code in the same code block (indent 
 them).